# PHP: How to avoid duplicated results in a foreach inside a foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I have a list of items: **userID**, **pagoID**, **cursoID**.

(Note: I'm testing the concept at the moment, didn't add any safety check yet).

The list is generated programatically, where I retrieve from the database the **userID** and the **pagoID**. I added a text input field beside each row for the admin to manually add the **cursoID**.

I've made a while loop in order to make the list:

```
while($x=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrarPagos)){
echo $x['pagoID'];
echo $x['userID'];
echo '<input name="verificarPago['.$x['pagoID'].']" type="text">';
};
```

I've added a submit button, and when it is submitted, the loop should insert into the database a new record with those three pieces of information. The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the **userID** as `$x['userID']` will live only inside the while loop that creates the table.

**So I've tried putting the userId into an input text, and set it as a readonly field. And then do a foreach loop inside another foreach loop.**

```
while($x=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrarPagos)){
echo $x['pagoID'];
echo '<input name="userID['.$x['userID'].']" value="'.$x['userID'].'" type="text">';
echo '<input name="verificarPago['.$x['pagoID'].']" type="text">';
};

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
      $verificar = $_POST['verificarPago'];
      foreach ($verificar as $pago => $curso) {
          $userID = $_POST['userID'];
          foreach ($userID as $usuario) {
          $verificarPago = "INSERT pagosVerificados SET userID = '$usuario', pagoID = '$pago', cursoID = '$curso'";
          $cargarPago = mysqli_query($conectar, $verificarPago);
        }
        if ($verificarPago && $cargarPago) {

        }
      }
```

**There are two rows in the table with this information (the cursoID is taken from what I type into the input field):**

```
userID. 17 pagoID. 4 cursoID. 18
userID. 18 pagoID. 5 cursoID. 15
```

**The result when I hit submit is this one:**

```
userID. 17 pagoID. 4 cursoID. 18
userID. 18 pagoID. 4 cursoID. 18
userID. 17 pagoID. 5 cursoID. 15
userID. 18 pagoID. 5 cursoID. 15
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pagos.pagoID, pagos.userID,  pagos.pagoMonto, pagos.pagoFecha, 
                pagos.pagoMedioUtilizado, pagos.pagoCuentaOrigen, pagos.pagoSucursal, 
                pagos.pagoCodigo,
                usuarios.userID, usuarios.userEmail,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cursos.nombreCurso, ' cid:', cursosUsuarios.cursoID ORDER BY cursosUsuarios.cursoID SEPARATOR '<br>') AS 'cursos'

                FROM pagos LEFT JOIN usuarios
                ON pagos.userID = usuarios.userID
                LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios
                ON usuarios.userID = cursosUsuarios.userID

                LEFT JOIN cursos
                ON cursosUsuarios.cursoID = cursos.cursoID
                AND cursos.estadoCurso = 'abierto'

                JOIN pagosVerificados
                WHERE pagos.pagoID NOT IN (SELECT pagoID FROM pagosVerificados)

                GROUP BY pagos.pagoID
```

Comment: use GROUP BY pagoID, cursoID in Your SELECT query

Comment: you can also use DISTINCT. However, you didn't include where your did the SELECT so we don't know if you are using any of those or not.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If You need answer to question so do this:

```
$alreadyHave = array();
while($x=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrarPagos)){
  if(in_array($x['pagoID'].'-'.$x['cursoID'], $alreadyHave)) {
    continue;
  }

  echo $x['pagoID'];
  echo '<input name="userID['.$x['userID'].']" value="'.$x['userID'].'"type="text">';
  echo '<input name="verificarPago['.$x['pagoID'].']" type="text">';
};
```

**BUT** technically it's better to have already unique data before iteration, so just put to the end of Your `SELECT` query: `GROUP BY pagoID, cursoID`

**ALSO** sanitize Your `INSERT` to database (to not to get downvotes by bug-sensitive developers because of Your sql-injectable code) (:

```
$verificarPago = "INSERT pagosVerificados SET ";
$verificarPago.= "  userID = ".(int)$usuario;
$verificarPago.= ", pagoID = ".(int)$pago;
$verificarPago.= ", cursoID = ".(int)$curso;
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, you can put userID in a hidden input if you don't want to display it (which was your first design choice)

```
<input type="hidden" id='userID' value="<? echo $x['pagoID'];?>"/>
```

I'm not sure about double entry but why not using one foreach only and using index for each input like you did for verificarPago
maybe you can replace

```
echo '<input name="userID['.$x['userID'].']" value="'.$x['userID'].'" type="text">
```

by

```
echo '<input name="userID['.$x['pagoID'].']" value="'.$x['userID'].'" type="text">
```

and then

```
  $userID = $_POST['userID'];
  //foreach ($userID as $usuario) {
  $verificarPago = "INSERT pagosVerificados SET userID = '$userID[$pago]', pagoID = '$pago', cursoID = '$curso'";
```

(did not test)

good luck